# PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line - Unable to decode JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization, jwt

I am trying to authenticate my JWT by decoding it and validating it. However I'm running into this issue and not sure where to turn. I'm using Node/Express

> Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

What I'm doing - sending in a token every request to make sure it's the correct token and once that happens the request can take place. I'm using it as a middleware.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const compression = require('compression')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer')
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const index = require('./routes/index')
const responseTime = require('response-time')
const fs = require('fs')
const jwtToken = require('express-jwt');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')
 };

const app = express()
// const app = express.createServer()
const port = 3000



//add authorization request header
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(403).json({ error: 'No credentials sent!'});
    }
    try {
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        var decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'your secret here');
        console.log(decoded, 'decoded!!!!')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('err ', err.stack);
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: 'invalid token'
        });
      }

    next();
})

app.use('/', index)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server started on port 3000')
})
```

The comment below is referring to an accidental duplicate because SO stored my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PEM routines:PEM\_read\_bio:no start line - Unable to decode JWT token.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481192/pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-line-unable-to-decode-jwt-token)

Comment: Just deleted the other one. For some reason, it stored my question and duplicated it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The error: `Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` can have different causes. I will provide a little list with causes and their solutions, ordered by how commonly I've seen them. Before you read any further please make sure that you are using public key for verify, private key for signing.

---

**The JavaScript String missing line problem**

When loading the key files or storing the keys in constants as strings you will be fine most of the time. However once you turn the `production` flag on, everything breaks:

```
// NODE_ENV=production

const PUB_KEY = `
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
`
```

To solve this problem you can use the `String.prototype.trim()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)) command on your constants: `PUB_KEY.trim()`. See also this comment on Github: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/400#issuecomment-397481574

---

**Windows file to Linux problem**

When moving files from Windows to Linux systems there is often the windows carriage return `^M` lurking around causing problems. 
Your file will then look like this when loaded:

```
^M
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----^M
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To solve it just use the following command: `sed -i 's/\r//' <filename>`.

---

**Base64 encoding problem**

Aside from the mentioned line breaks like above, there is a chance that the encoding will not be set properly. Be careful as it can happen that your private key and your public key will have a mismatch then. This happens most of the time if you use:

- For decoding: `new Buffer(process.env.MY_PUBLIC_KEY, 'base64').toString('utf-8')`
- For verify: `jwt.verify(my_token, my_decoded_public_ky, { algorithms: ['RS256']), (err, payload) => { ... });`

To solve this problem you can simply check that your encoding is set to `utf-8` and the original line breaks are preserved.

Your key must have been generated with this command: `openssl base64 -in mykey.pem -out mykey_encoded.pem && echo $(<mykey_encoded.pem) | tr -d ' ' > mykey_encoded.pem`.

See also this comment on Github: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/400#issuecomment-377516270